# Select link of certain class within body of certain class

Tags: html, css, magento

What is the correct way to select a link of a certain class within a body of specific class. For example my body has the class "abc" and my link has the class "efg", what would my css code look like? (I'm trying to create active links for a Magento block)

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: Thanks Ibu. worked. I had my a tag after; which usually works for psuedo classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
body.body_class a.link_class
```

This question is a bit basic - you should try to learn this stuff a bit.

Comment: @Sam Go to sleep, you'll program faster.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do some research

```
body.abc a.efg {
   rules
}
```

even [w3c](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) can help you with that

Answer (score 0):

You should write something like this:

```
.abc .efg {

     /*Your CSS Rules*/
 }
```

### [**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/uQHCF/)

Answer (score 0):

Check this example

```
<html> 
<head>      
<style>
.outer
{
    background-color: red;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.inner
{
    background-color: blue;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 5px;
}

.outer .inner
{
background-color: green;
}
</style>
</head>

<body  onload="loadCars()">

Check div style.
<div  id="mydiv" class="inner">
</div>

</div>
<div  id="mydiv" class="outer">
<div  id="mydiv" class="inner"></div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Save the above code in an html file and open it.